# SQL Server CLR 'Failed to create AppDomain' debugging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-clr

I am having the 'Failed to create AppDomain' issue in a production instance. This is typically attributed to memory pressure(not the case here) or pending .Net updates. The OS has been restarted and the issue persists.

```
Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (Intel X86) 
    May 14 2014 16:44:52 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)
```

Moving beyond the simple solutions, it seems as if the only other troubleshooting step is look at the created dump file. The .Net subsystem in the OS seems otherwise healthy. I can create programs that reference System.Data and run with no issues.

What other tools exist to troubleshoot issues in the CLR feature of SQL Server?

The full error is-

> DESCRIPTION:    Failed to create AppDomain "master.sys[runtime].52".
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
> dependencies. Not enough storage is available to process this command.
>
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

Comment: Are you aware you have 32 bit SQL Server running on 64 bit OS. In this case SQL Server cannot use more than 4 GB under default conditions and SQLCLR has always been problematic with 32 bit version due to lack of VAS. I suggest you upgrade to 64 bit version of SQL Server 2012 and I believe issue will resolve.

Comment: What are you doing when you get this error? Are you using the Microsoft provided CLR types (Geometry / Geography / HierarchyID)? Do you have custom SQLCLR? If so, does this error always happen, or only sometimes? Has it ever worked? Have you updated the .NET framework on this server recently? Can you try running a repair for the .NET framework to see if that helps?

Comment: Yeah, @Shanky - That was not how the server was supposed to be provisioned originally and I had not even considered that as a possible failure mode. Who in their right mind still uses 32b SQL Server? Having exhausted other possibilities, I ran SP_Blitz which made the problem obvious.